# How to insert two entries into database using two textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a form on which I have many textboxes, but two textboxes are same for one data field. I want to put both those textboxes' values individual in a SQL database.

Comment: Please have a read this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: can you show us your code and what you have tried till now to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind same field into textboxes via BindingSource component.